# WordPress Multisite: Activate / Deactivate a Plugin of a Specific Blog

Tags: wordpress, multisite, wp-cli

Programmatically, I want to activate / deactivate a plugin of this specific blog/site in a WordPress Multisite. Any help will be gladly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you don't need to network-activate the plugin on all sites in the main site - You can just install it, and activate it on the sub sites where needed

Comment: I am writing a plugin, so I need it programmatically.

Comment: you can deactivate it though a function for a specific site - if you have the ID for that site - or do you want a setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. From your Network Dashboard go to any subsite dashboard

   [image]
2. Then go to Plugins and activate plugin on this specific blog

In case you want to do it programmatically you can use activate_plugins() or deactivate_plugins() after a switch_to_blog( $blog_id ) function, example:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'true_plugin_off_in_theme' );

function true_plugin_off_in_theme() {
    switch_to_blog( 'PASS_BLOG_ID_HERE' );
    deactivate_plugins( 'true-instagram-widget/true-instagram-widget.php' );
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: How about for theme? **Programmatically Activate / Deactivate the theme of a Specific Blog**

Comment: The same, but switch_theme() function

Comment: Cool! I gotta try it. Thank you so much Misha!

Answer (score 3):

### Via WP-CLI

*Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/activate/*

**Syntax:**

```
$ wp plugin activate [plugins...] --url=<url>
```

---

**Usage:**

- Activate Single Plugin:

```
$ wp plugin activate akismet --url="example.com"
```

- Activate Multiple Plugins:

```
$ wp plugin activate akismet jetpack ninja-forms --url="example.com"
```